# How can i change django admin to rtl style

Tags: python, django

First of all i'm new to `django` . and i'm amazing from this cool framework (not in `database` part and `mysql` connector)

And When i looking to django admin style folder in css folder ,

i see rtl css , but now i don't know how can i change admin style to `rtl` .

This is screen shot from my folders

[image]

Thank's

Answer (score 12):

Try setting your language code in settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa-ir'
```

for further reading on translating, rtl, changing date format and other localization things read [this django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/#term-translation-string).

Answer (score 4):

Django looks at the TEMPLATES setting to find order to check for templates to render. As such, you can add `rtl.css` to the head of the base admin template in order to load the right-to-left css.

1. In a templates sub-directory of your main project directory, create dir `admin` and file `base.html`. Copy the contents of 'django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html' from Django's source to the newly created file.

   `TEMPLATES = [
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # <- add this line
           'APP_DIRS': True,
           'OPTIONS': {
               'context_processors': [
                   'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                   'django.template.context_processors.request',
                   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
               ],
           },
       },
   ]`
2. In the template, you'll see `{% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}`. Insert the stylesheet link here, like this-

   `{% block extra_head %}
       <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static 'admin/css/rtl.css' %}' />
   {% endblock %}`

Now `rtl.css` will be loaded whenever any admin page is loaded.

Comment: You can just copy the much smaller file `base_site.html` and add the same block. `base_site.html` is located at the same level of `base.html` and is already extending `base.html`.